# Using Twitter Widget to display tweets and add hidden text behind the tweet

Tags: javascript, twitter

This is a bit of a weird question. I am working on an app in HTML/CSS/Javascript and displaying tweets using the [Twitter widget](https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js). Everything is working fine and I will post my code below.

The challenge I am encountering is this:

When displaying posts with sensitive content, the widget shows a "not found" image instead of the post. As far as I know, there's no way of capturing those and linking to the post instead. However, for the user experience, I'd like to be able to allow them to click a link to view the post.  My idea for achieving this is to have some text ("click here to see the post") that takes them to the actual post on twitter, since I do have the post ID.  I want to place this text so that if the tweet is not sensitive content and does appear, it will overlay the text, effectively hiding it...and then the user will only see that text if they get the "not found" image.

However I am completely stumped on getting the text to show up. Wherever I try to add it, the column styling gets completely screwed up, or the text ends up replacing the "not found" image. It's tricky because once I pass the post ID and the parent div to the widget, it auto-generates the rest of the code and I can't manipulate it from there.

Wondering if anyone has ideas for how to get around this. See below for code - not sure why it isn't working when I run it here, guessing it has to do with the widget dependency.

```js
const populatePosts = () => {
  // Post data
  let postList = [{
      post_id: "1754905910126968944",
      post_type: "TW",
    },
    {
      post_id: "1755026979865424073",
      post_type: "TW",
    },
    {
      post_id: "1756059288865521797",
      post_type: "TW",
    },
  ];

  // TWEETS \\
  let post_id;

  if (postList.length > 0) {
    // set up the variables
    var subs;
    var col1 = "",
      col2 = "",
      col3 = "";
    var column_index = 1;

    // loop through the results to build the three column strings
    for (subs = 0; subs < postList.length; subs++) {
      if (column_index == 1) {
        col1 +=
          "<div class='embed-responsive' id='tweetArea" + subs + "'></div>";
      } else if (column_index == 2) {
        col2 +=
          "<div class='embed-responsive' id='tweetArea" + subs + "'></div>";
      } else if (column_index == 3) {
        col3 +=
          "<div class='embed-responsive' id='tweetArea" + subs + "'></div>";
      }
      column_index += 1;
      if (column_index == 4) {
        column_index = 1;
      }
    }

    // write out the column html code
    document.getElementById(`tweetCol1`).innerHTML = col1;
    document.getElementById(`tweetCol2`).innerHTML = col2;
    document.getElementById(`tweetCol3`).innerHTML = col3;

    // loop through the results to display the tweets
    for (subs = 0; subs < postList.length; subs++) {
      // get the post id
      post_id = postList[subs];

      // build the twitter area name
      let twitter_area = "tweetArea" + subs;

      // display the tweets
      twttr.widgets
        .createTweet(
          postList[subs].post_id,
          document.getElementById(twitter_area), {}
        )
        .then(function(e1) {
          // If any of the tweets return "undefined", that means it's been deleted. Update the counter so we can display a message to the user about how many tweets have been deleted
          if (e1 === undefined) {
            postsCounter += 1;
          }
          // If counter is > 0, display deleted posts summary
          // Grab the deleted summary div from the DOM
          let deletedSummaryDivPositive = $(`#deleted-post-summary-text`);
          if (postsCounter > 0) {
            $(deletedSummaryDivPositive).text(
              `We detected ${postsCounter} post(s) that were deleted or are no longer available.`
            );
            $(deletedSummaryDivPositive).show();
          } else {
            $(deletedSummaryDivPositive).hide();
          }
        })
        .catch(function(e2) {});
    }
  }
};
```

```html
<!-- Twitter widget -->
<script sync src="https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js"></script>

<!-- tweets container -->
<div class="container-fluid tweets-container" id="tweets-container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3" id="tweetCol1"></div>

        <div class="col-md-1"></div>

        <div class="col-md-3" id="tweetCol2"></div>

        <div class="col-md-1"></div>
        <div class="col-md-3" id="tweetCol3"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- /tweets container -->
```